# MVC query model data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC site I am displaying data from my model in a table in the view. On the first column (which is a unique number within the model data) I have made it into a click-able link that displays an alert box using jQuery.

What I would like to do is when the link is clicked it queries the model for another piece of data using this unique number and displays that in the alert.

Would someone be able to help me with the query I would need to write?

Comment: Help yourself first. Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Backbone.js

http://backbonejs.org/

What you describe is a perfect example of a collection of models, by clicking on one of them you want to fetch the full model from the server.

With Backbone.js this is easy made and whats even better, you can easy save changed date without writing complex code to do it.

```
var Model = new Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: 'www.call-this.com/to-fetch-from-server/1'

}).

//gets the data from the api
Model.fetch()

//sends data to the same defined api via post
Model.save()
```

You might have great fun with Backbone ;)

Comment: This does not answer OP question